# Pandas - AttributeError: Can't get attribute '_unpickle_block' on (which version of pandas was used to pickle?)

Tags: pandas

I know there are lots on this issue and I have solved this using same before. But now I am trying to read a pickle file and which ever version of pandas I try I get same error. Is there a way to know version of pandas using which pickle file was made ? Unfortunately due to reasons there is no way to find out the earlier environment. Would appreciate if there is a way around?